# Why does Visual Studio offer split code viewing

Tags: visual-studio

I just recently realized that Visual Studio offers the ability to split the code view into 2 sections (top and bottom). Now, having played with it a bit, if you make changes in one, it affects the other. My question is, what is the purpose of this? How do people use it?

In case you're unaware of this, one way of splitting the code view is by moving this slider circled in the picture:

[image]

Comment: So you can see two different parts of the class at the same time.  Presumably, they relate to each other in some way, so it's handy to see both on the screen at the same time.

Comment: With the usefulness of intellisense nowadays, it isn't as necessary, but for me, a lot of the time it might be to split the file because some constants or other useful information might be declared at the top, so I want to keep that visible while I use it below.

Answer (score 3):

**Code Review**

I occasionally use it to view a method that is called from another method during a code review. For instance, if I am code reviewing method A, and it calls B, and I want to see A and B at the same time, I will pull that down, and scroll one to B, and leave the other at A.

```
private void A()
{
    // code here
    B();
}

// other methods here that push B out of the viewable area.

private void B()
{
    // code here
}
```

**Pro Tip**

Another way to flip back and forth with just the keyboard, although you wouldn't see both methods at the same time, is to hit <kbd>F12</kbd> on the call to B within A, which is a shortcut to "Go To Definition", and then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, which is a shortcut for "Navigate Backwards", which brings you back to where your cursor was previously. I frequently use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to navigate forwards, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to navigate backwards.

**Trivia**

This extra viewing pane isn't exclusive to Visual Studio. You will notice Sql Server Management Studio, MS Word, and MS Outlook have the same functionality. I presume many other apps do too.

Answer (score 2):

Viewing Multiple Functions, Classes, or anything can be viewed.. whenever you want to see multiple things at a time, this split view can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to find a need for this option in professional development. If your code has grown big enough and you need this feature, chances are that refactoring would be better instead. Always use OOP to make sure you spend as little time navigating or remembering your code as possible.

Considering the above, I *can* see a potential for it in large projects with lots of unorganized old code, which you inherited from previous developers. Examples include one big Sub main, spanning thousands lines of code, procedural approach in development etc.

This feature truly shines in single document projects, such as in Word. Or multi-document projects where splitting into smaller files/classes is not always possible, such as in SQL Mgmt Studio.